# Jenkins Permission to Copy Artifact is always granted

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to make our Jenkins setup more secure, but I am unable to protect artifacts with the `Permission to Copy Artifact` option.

I have two jobs, where the downstream job copies artifacts from the upstream job by using the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin). This works as expected. Now I want to ensure that only *this specific downstream job* can copy the artifacts of the upstream job, but that doesn't seem to work.

As far as I understand, you should specify the name of the downstream job in the `Permission to Copy Artifact` option of the upstream job. I tried this, but no matter what I configure in the `Permission to Copy Artifact` option of the upstream job, the downstream job is *always allowed* to copy the artifacts.

So I would like to know: are there any global options that must be enabled or disabled for this to work? Is there something else that I must configure before the `permission to Copy Artifact` option actually limits permissions?

Edit: I'm using version Copy Artifact Plugin 1.38.1.

Answer (score 2):

Since Copyartifact 1.30, there is a limitation "Permission to Copy Artifacts" accepts only relative project names.
If you use CloudBees Folders Plugin and the projects are located in different folders, you need to specify project names like "../folder/project".
This is fixed in Copyartifact 1.31.

detail link : https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin